# Retrieving Images from Resource folder in C# windows form application

Tags: c#

I am developing project in C# windows application. I am new to this technology. I declared Image variable in one class and list in another class. I want to retrieve image from Resource folder and store it in list ten times. I wrote code like this but it is returning null.

```
class clsAddImage
    {
       public Image m_imgSampleImage;
    }
class clsList
    {
        public List<clsAddImage> lstImage = new List<clsAddImage>();   
    }
class clsAddImageToList
    {
        public void AddImgMethod()
        {
            clsList objlist = new clsList();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                clsAddImage objaddimg = new clsAddImage();
                objlist.lstImage.Add(objaddimg);
            }

            foreach (clsAddImage addimg in objlist.lstImage)
            {
                string path = "C:\\Users\\c09684\\Documents\\Visual Studio         2010\\Projects\\WindowsFormsAddImage\\WindowsFormsAddImage\\Resources\\Chrysanthemum.jpg";
                addimg.m_imgSampleImage = Image.FromFile(path);

            }

            }
    }
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clsAddImageToList a = new clsAddImageToList();
          a.AddImgMethod();
    }
```

Comment: Do you know which line causes the problem? If not, did you try to run the code in a debugger? If not, then please do so.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you refer to a Windows8 app? In that case you can **not** simply program a directory to retrieve information. The user has to choose a directory manually, which you can store for future use. However, you can have access to KnownFolders (for most you have to check Capabilities in  the Package.appxmanifest, e.g. Pictures Library), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders for the options.

With the following task you will be able to retrieve files from a directory, I hope this helps you solving your problem:

```
public async Task GetFilesFromDisk()
{
    StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
    StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();             

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await picturesFolder.GetFilesAsync(); 
    var images = new List<BitmapImage>();
    if (fileList != null)
    {
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            string cExt = file.FileType;

            if (cExt.ToUpper() == ".JPG") 
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream filestream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }   // ForEach
    }

}
```